# Unable to load data into logstash

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to follow the guide on the link below:

http://www.viaboxx.de/code/easily-generate-live-heatmaps-for-geolocations-with-elk/#codesyntax_1

It worked fine for me the first time but when I try it now, it gives me the following error at a step where I'm trying to load the csv data. The command I execute is:

```html
cat test.csv | /opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f geostore.conf
```

and I get the following error:

```html
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 2
Pipeline main started
Error parsing csv {:field=>"message", :source=>"", :exception=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method `each_index' for nil:NilClass>, :level=>:warn}
Pipeline main has been shutdown
stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
```

Can you please help !!! I've spent days on it trying to figure out.

**Edit** adding the geostore.conf:

```html
 input { stdin {} } 
    filter { # Step 1, drop the csv header line 
       if [message] =~ /^#/ { 
          drop {} 
        } # Step 2, split latitude and longitude 
        csv { 
          separator => ',' 
          columns => [ 'lat', 'lon' ] } 
           # Step 3 # move lat and lon into location object # for defined geo_point type in ES 
        mutate { 
             rename => [ "lat", "[location][lat]", "lon", "[location][lon]" ] 
         } 
       } 
    output { 
       elasticsearch {
         hosts => 'localhost' 
         index => 'geostore' 
         document_type => "locality" 
         flush_size => 1000 
      } 
    }
```

I've changed my output section from this:

```html
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => 'localhost'
    index => 'geostore'
    document_type  => "locality"
    flush_size => 1000
  }
```

to this

```html
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => 'localhost'
    index => 'geostore'
    document_type  => "locality"
    flush_size => 1000
    stdout {}
  }
```

and now I'm getting a bit more verbose error message:

```html
    fetched an invalid config {:config=>"input {\n    stdin {}\n}\nfilter {\n  #
 Step 1, drop the csv header line\n  if [message] =~ /^#/ {\n    drop {}\n  }\n 
\n  # Step 2, split latitude and longitude\n  csv {\n    separator => ','\n    
columns => [ 'lat', 'lon' ]\n  }\n \n  # Step 3\n  # move lat and lon into 
location object \n  # for defined geo_point type in ES\n  mutate {  \n    rename 
=> [ \"lat\", \"[location][lat]\", \"lon\", \"[location][lon]\" ]\n  
}\n}\noutput {\n  elasticsearch {\n    hosts => 'localhost'\n    index => 
'geostore'\n    document_type  => \"locality\"\n    flush_size => 1000\n    
stdout {}\n  }\n}\n\n", :reason=>"Expected one of #, => at line 29, column 12 
(byte 543) after output {\n  elasticsearch {\n    hosts => 'localhost'\n    
index => 'geostore'\n    document_type  => \"locality\"\n    flush_size => 
1000\n    stdout ", :level=>:error}
```

Can't understand why it worked for the first time.

```html
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 2
Pipeline main started
Error parsing csv {:field=>"message", :source=>"", :exception=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method `each_index' for nil:NilClass>, :level=>:warn}
2017-03-30T13:46:31.171Z localhost.localdomain 53.97917361, -6.389038611
2017-03-30T13:46:31.171Z localhost.localdomain 54.00310028, -6.397707778
2017-03-30T13:46:31.172Z localhost.localdomain 53.99960056, -6.381966111
2017-03-30T13:46:31.172Z localhost.localdomain 54.00534917, -6.423718889
2017-03-30T13:46:31.172Z localhost.localdomain 51.92071667, -8.475726111
2017-03-30T13:46:31.172Z localhost.localdomain 51.82731222, -8.381912222
2017-03-30T13:46:31.173Z localhost.localdomain 51.81096639, -8.415731667
2017-03-30T13:46:31.173Z localhost.localdomain 54.28450222, -8.463775556
2017-03-30T13:46:31.173Z localhost.localdomain 54.27841, -8.495700278
2017-03-30T13:46:31.173Z localhost.localdomain 54.2681225, -8.462056944
2017-03-30T13:46:31.174Z localhost.localdomain 52.276167, -9.680497
2017-03-30T13:46:31.174Z localhost.localdomain 52.25660139, -9.703921389
2017-03-30T13:46:31.174Z localhost.localdomain 52.27031306, -9.723975556
2017-03-30T13:46:31.174Z localhost.localdomain 54.95663111, -7.714384167
2017-03-30T13:46:31.175Z localhost.localdomain 54.00133111, -7.352790833
2017-03-30T13:46:31.175Z localhost.localdomain 52.34264222, -6.4854175
2017-03-30T13:46:31.176Z localhost.localdomain 52.32439028, -6.464626111
2017-03-30T13:46:31.176Z localhost.localdomain 52.33008944, -6.487005
2017-03-30T13:46:31.176Z localhost.localdomain 53.70765861, -6.374657778
2017-03-30T13:46:31.177Z localhost.localdomain 53.72636306, -6.326768611
2017-03-30T13:46:31.177Z localhost.localdomain 53.71461361, -6.336066111
2017-03-30T13:46:31.177Z localhost.localdomain 51.55948417, -9.244535833
2017-03-30T13:46:31.177Z localhost.localdomain 53.52894667, -7.358543056
2017-03-30T13:46:31.177Z localhost.localdomain 53.51801167, -7.324215
2017-03-30T13:46:31.179Z localhost.localdomain 53.16202278, -6.795522222
2017-03-30T13:46:31.179Z localhost.localdomain 53.182702, -6.819299
2017-03-30T13:46:31.179Z localhost.localdomain 52.83053972, -8.991989444
2017-03-30T13:46:31.180Z localhost.localdomain 52.85651944, -8.965725833
2017-03-30T13:46:31.180Z localhost.localdomain 53.02885028, -7.300381667
2017-03-30T13:46:31.180Z localhost.localdomain
Pipeline main has been shutdown
stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
```

Comment: What Logstash version are you using? Could you post as well your geostore.conf just to be sure there is no issues with it? Lastly, in the output section, could you add `stdout{codec => rubydebug}`, as I have found that it often helps finding the issue

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Please see my geostore.conf. My logstash version is 2.3.4

Comment: It works fine for me, are you sure about your csv file? As I mentioned, try using the stdout in the output section to get more details on the issue. What you can try as well is to feed one line directly without using your test.csv, like 50.98474812, 7.47645034

Comment: Sorry forgot to as you. How can I enter a line directly? Can you please give the command syntax?

Comment: You wait that "Main pipeline started" is written, then you write on stdin, By the way your error when putting stdout is because you included it in the elasticsearch section instead of the output section.

Comment: Jeez. You are eagle eyed :) Please see my output this time.

Comment: And I'm guessing you see the data in Elasticsearch/Kibana right? I can't reproduce your error unfortunately ...  Though a few recommendations would be, use the latest version (even 2.4 if you cannot make the jump to version 5), and given that your logstash fails only when reading the first line ("#Latitude, Longitude"), you might also get rid of it in your csv file, as this line is anyway not used at all by Logstash

Comment: Hiya,
Not sure exactly what happend but I deleted the pattern with  curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/geostore?pretty'
 and then went to to kibana to delete it from there as well. Reloaded the pattern back again and followed all the steps from the link that I posted above and it worked. I suppose your troubleshooting helped to point me in the right direction. Thanks  a mill :) How do I mark you as an answer?

Comment: I think you should write an answer to your questions with the steps you followed to solve the issue (in the section below your question, after posting it, you can tag it as the answer). I just helped, it's not really an answer per say.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefull, this would help other's as well.

I deleted the pattern from the command line:

```html
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/geostore?pretty';
```

and then went to to kibana to delete it from there as well. Reloaded the pattern back again as below and it worked.

```html
    curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/geostore'
```

```html
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/geostore/_mapping/locality' -d '
{
   "locality" : {
       "properties" : {
              "location" : {
                  "type" : "geo_point",
                  "geohash_prefix":     true,
                  "geohash_precision":  "1km"
              }
          }
       }
}'
```

```html
cat test.csv | /opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f geostore.conf
```

This will take a few seconds to startup logstash, parse the input and store the result into Elasticsearch.

Now that we have the data in Elasticsearch, let's move to Kibana 4. After logged into Kibana, you need to add the index to Kibana.

Go to: Settings -> Indices -> Add New -> Write "geostore" in the index name field.

After you add the index, you'll see all fields in  the documents of the index, especially you should check if the property location is  classified as geo_point.

The whole process is described in detail at the below link.

http://www.viaboxx.de/code/easily-generate-live-heatmaps-for-geolocations-with-elk/#codesyntax_1